# Input name in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Probably simple question but how wrote name of input in jQuery:

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="user[profile_attributes][birthdate(3i)]" value="3">
```

JQUERY:

This doesn't seems to work or bug is somewhere else:

```
jQuery('input[name="user[profile_attributes][birthdate(3i)"]')
```

Comment: you're missing one `]` at the end of selector

Comment: typo: 
`jQuery('input[name="user[profile_attributes][birthdate(3i)"]')` <--- `"]` should be `]"`. https://jsfiddle.net/2sgetdpL/ (your current querySelector is looking for `input[name="user[profile_attributes][birthdate(3i)` instead of `input[name="user[profile_attributes][birthdate(3i)]` )

Comment: Thanks typo and hide() + diable,true to do not send var in form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your J query selector it should be:

```
jQuery('input[name="user[profile_attributes][birthdate(3i)]"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Also you can save the data in different's attribut

   ```
   <input type="hidden" name="user[profile_attributes][birthdate(3i)]" value="3">
   ```

for this

```
<input type="hideen" name="VALUE" profile="VALUE" birthday="VALUE">
```

3. Then, with jquery, extract the values with:

   var name = $(this).attr(name);

   var profile= $(this).attr(profile);

   var birthday = $(this).attr(birthday);

Or save it as an object with ajax:

```
var data = {name:$(this).attr(name), profile:$(this).attr(profile), birthday:$(this).attr(birthday)};
```